# Streamlining Data Retrieval from API

Tags: java, spring, pagination, cloud

**Objective**:
The objective is to provide a solution for efficiently retrieving a list of spelling errors from question text, answer text, and option text really fast. Current process is really slow and requires some manual work. The desired outcome is to automate the process and overcome issues related to gateway timeout exception and Java heap size out of memory.

**Current Implementation:**

Implemented an API with pagination which will give an Excel file having `questionId`, `questionText`, `answerText`, `optionText`, list of misspelled words in all of them.

**Challenges**:

1. Large Data Volume: There are over 600k data entries tagged under spelling errors, making it challenging to retrieve all the data at once.
2. Pagination Limitations: The API allows fetching a maximum of 500 data entries per request, necessitating the need to change the page size frequently.
3. Timeout Exception: Attempting to fetch a large number of data entries simultaneously results in timeout exceptions.
4. Java Heap Size Out of Memory: Handling significant amounts of data concurrently leads to heap size exhaustion.

I am expecting to automate it with page and size and also if there is any better implementation to efficiently do that making the process faster